# Error rendering Kendo UI DropDownList bound to remote DataSource

Tags: kendo-ui

I'm facing a Problem with a DowpDownList Widget that's bound to a Kendo DataSource that gets its data from a ASP.NET webservice. The error get's thrown in StaticList's _render method on line 22199:

```
var isGrouped = this.dataSource.group().length;
```

The reason for the error is that the group() method returns an empty object and not an Array as exptected.

This is the Definition of my widget:

```
<input id="contactFunctionId"
        name="FunctionID"
        data-role="dropdownlist"
        data-bind="value:FunctionID,
                    source: panelFunctions"
        data-value-field="FunctionID"
        data-text-field="Title"
        data-auto-bind="false"
        class="k-textbox"
        required="required" />
```

And this is the Definition of the DataSource (data is actually loaded just not rendered):

```
this.PanelFunctions = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    type: "odata",
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: function () {
                return ns.cnfg("crudServiceBaseUrl") + '/GetCommunityFunctions';
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false
        },
        parameterMap: KTGR.AMZADB.SanitizeparameterMap
    },
    group: new Array(),
    schema: {
        model: FunctionModel,
        data: function (response) {
            return response;
        },
        total: function (data) {
            return data.length;
        },
    },
    error: logError,
    serverPaging: false,
    serverFiltering: true,
    serverSorting: false,
    requestStart: LogDataSourceRequestStart,
    requestEnd: LogDataSourceRequestEnd
});
```

I have a bunch of similar DataSources configured to work with other widgets like AutoComplete, ListView etc. and none of them shows the same weird behaviour. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated since I'm banging my head on this for days now!